# Creating new variable by focusing range of other variables

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr, data-cleaning

I want to create a variable that include all numbers between (startyear) and (endyear - 1). My data looks like this:

| country | leader | startyear | endyear |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| US | Eisenhower | 1953 | 1961 |
| US | Kennedy | 1961 | 1963 |

I want to show my data like this:

| country | leader | startyear | endyear | year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| US | Eisenhower | 1953 | 1961 | 1953 |
| US | Eisenhower | 1953 | 1961 | 1954 |
| US | Eisenhower | 1953 | 1961 | 1955 |
| US | Eisenhower | 1953 | 1961 | 1956 |
| US | Eisenhower | 1953 | 1961 | 1957 |
| US | Eisenhower | 1953 | 1961 | 1958 |
| US | Eisenhower | 1953 | 1961 | 1959 |
| US | Eisenhower | 1953 | 1961 | 1960 |
| US | Kennedy | 1961 | 1963 | 1961 |
| US | Kennedy | 1961 | 1963 | 1962 |

I have many countries in data set. I want to manipulate all data set with "the" code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may get the sequence (`:`) by row and `unnest` the `list` column

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(year = map2(startyear, endyear-1, `:`)) %>%
   unnest(year)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 × 5
   country leader     startyear endyear  year
   <chr>   <chr>          <int>   <int> <int>
 1 US      Eisenhower      1953    1961  1953
 2 US      Eisenhower      1953    1961  1954
 3 US      Eisenhower      1953    1961  1955
 4 US      Eisenhower      1953    1961  1956
 5 US      Eisenhower      1953    1961  1957
 6 US      Eisenhower      1953    1961  1958
 7 US      Eisenhower      1953    1961  1959
 8 US      Eisenhower      1953    1961  1960
 9 US      Kennedy         1961    1963  1961
10 US      Kennedy         1961    1963  1962
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(country = c("US", "US"), leader = c("Eisenhower", 
"Kennedy"), startyear = c(1953L, 1961L), endyear = c(1961L, 1963L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```